# Finding holomorphic functions to satisfy specific criteria on natural numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

So I'm revising Complex Analysis and I'm quite stuck on this question. I've been asked to determine whether there is a holomorphic function on $\Bbb{C}$ that satisfies this condition for all positive integers n: 
$$f(\frac 1n)=(-1)^n\sin(\frac 1n)$$
Firstly, I am a bit confused about what I am actually looking to find, and secondly how to get there? We were just asked to state the Identity Theorem, so I'm thinking I'll need to apply this in some way, I'm just not sure where to even begin.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(z): = \sin z$ and $f$ as above. Then we have

$g(\frac{1}{2n})=f(\frac{1}{2n})$ for all $n$ . By the identity theorem we get $f=g$ on $ \mathbb C.$

But this contradicts $f(\frac 1n)=(-1)^nsin(\frac 1n)$, if $n $ is odd.

Therefore no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this now. Am I right in thinking that in the case h((n/n+1)^2)=n/(n+1) there is no such function, as the only one I can think of is the square root function, which is not holomorphic on the whole complex plane, only on a cut plane?

Comment: Suppose that there is an entire function $h$ such that $h((\frac{n}{n+1})^2)= \frac{n}{n+1}.$ for all $n$. Then put $f(z)=h(z^2).$ By the identity theorem we get $f(z)=z.$, hence $z=h(z^2)$. Differentiation gives $1=2z h(z^2)$. With $z=0$ we derive the contradiction that $1=0.$

Answer (score 1):

$g(z)=f(z)-\sin \,z$ is holomorphic and $g(\frac1 {2n})=0$ for all $n$. Since $\{\frac  1{2n}: n \geq 1\}$ has a limit point it follows (by the Identity Theorem) that $g(z)=0$ for all $z$ which means $f(z)=\sin \,z$ for all $z$. But then the given equation fails for $n$ odd, so there is no such function.